# AspectJ Performance logging for ModelAttribute and Get/Post combined

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

With AspectJ, is there a means of logging a GET or a POST that includes not just the GET and POST, but also the time that was spent on the ModelAttributes?

For example:

```
    @ModelAttribute
    public void populateModel(Model model, HttpSession session) { ... }
```

Plus

```
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String  handleGet(HttpSession session, ModelMap model) { ... }
```

Logged as a single transaction? What I'm seeing is that I may have to take the ModelAttribute time and add it to the Get time.

Ideally, I'd have an annotation pointcut that is placed at the beginning of my class and it would trigger the Advice for the entirety of the users page load:

```
    @PerformanceLogAnnotation(valueOne=true)
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value="/pageTest.html")
    public class TestController { ... }
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to log independent execution time of `populateModel()` and `handleGet()` method, right?

Comment: Yes, such that the log method isn't called twice, but just once for the combined event of `populateModel()` and `handleGet()`.

Comment: I don't that's possible with just one call for log() method. When you weave aspect with methods it will weave to both and log time independently.

Comment: I think you are right Harshil. I've gone with a different means of logging with an interceptor, as described here: http://www.myjavarecipes.com/spring-profilingaudit-using-mvc-interceptors/